# Neo4j remote access from windows using putty

Tags: neo4j

I installed Neo4j 3.2.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I tried to access it remotely using putty (from my windows-based computers). Without uncommenting anything in neo4j.conf, I can access Neo4j using the source port I defined in putty. Then, after connecting with the initial password "Neo4j" in the section saying "Connect to Neo4j Database access requires an authenticated connection.", I gets the famous error "ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine ...".

So, after googling, I uncommented:

dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

BUT NOTHING WORKS.

The interesting thing is that I tried to install Neo4j on my laptop (locally) and it worked and when I used its "bolt://..." database access password on my remote access "bolt://..." database access it works.So, I'm not sure what is going on here, can someone help?

Comment: Now ... when you say you were able to reach it without uncommenting anything ... that's impossible (by default the database is only reachable on the localhost) unless you did a port forward in putty. Did you ? And if so, did you forward both port 7474 and port 7687.

Comment: If you have uncommented the listen_address (and restarted Neo4j ... don't forget that) and are not using port forwarding ... are ports 7474 and 7687 reachable from your Windows machine ? What does nmap (started from your Windows machine) show (nmap -p 7474 <ip ubuntu host>) ?

Comment: I used SSH->Tunnels in putty to forward ubuntu localhost:7474 (destination) to my laptop port "8007"  and I also tried to make another port for ubuntu localhost:7687  (bolt://) but it didn't work. The only thing that happened is that I accessed the Neo4j interface but I couldn't access the database with the initial password 'neo4j'. Then, I uncommented: dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0  and dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687. But nothing happened. I kept getting ""ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure...."error

Comment: You need both ubuntu server ports (7474 and 7687) accessible on your windows machine. If you don't have both (as you say) ... you get the error you describe. Now, if you have uncommented the listen_address (and restarted Neo4j after that), you do not need the tunnel. You should be able to access the server directly in your browser with http://<ip ubuntu server>:7474 and bolt://<ip ubuntu server>:7687. However, the firewall on the ubuntu server may block that access ... so you have to allow access to those ports.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I forwarded ubuntu localhost:7474 and localhost:7687 to my windows 7474 and 7687 ports (I used the same port numbers) without uncommenting anything and worked.